# Optimizing load and search speeds ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, performance, dataset

I'm completely new to ASP.NET, however after some struggle with basics and thanks to google I managed to set up a page to suit my needs.

Web Application is supposed to load data from XML file that I generate with another Windows application on localhost, display this data and allow users to search it.

This XML file has more than 50 MB and more than 120.000 entries.

I'm reading this XML file into dataset which then I bind to gridView.

Problem is :

- When I load page first time it can take up to 30 seconds
- When I search data loading can take more than 10 seconds

How can I solve this ? 
I tried StateView, however that results in "Ran out of Memory" exception.
I did some research and it appears I can save this dataset in server cache, which would allow it to be instantly accessible to all users, without the need to reload XML every time for each user ?

This is my code at the moment, please let me know if something is bad since I have no idea about ASP.NET. Thanks.

```
 public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public DataSet resultDS = new DataSet();
    public bool searchListActive = false;
    string _sortDirection = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridView_IndexData.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddList_DataCount.SelectedItem.Value);
            ViewState["searchListActive"] = false;
            BindCB();
        }

        gridView_IndexData.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddList_DataCount.SelectedItem.Value);
    }



    void BindGrid()
    {
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/lstData.xml"));
        gridView_IndexData.DataSource = ds;
        gridView_IndexData.DataBind();
    }

    void BindCB()
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "forumName");
        var DR = dt.NewRow();
        DR["forumName"] = "All forums";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(DR, 0);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        ddList_Forum.DataSource = dt;
        ddList_Forum.DataTextField = "forumName";
        ddList_Forum.DataBind();
    }



    protected void btnSearchQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultDS = ds.Clone();

        string searchQuery = "";

        searchQuery = "TopicTitle LIKE '%" + tbSearchInput.Text + "%'";

        if (tbSearchByUsername.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            searchQuery += "AND UserName ='" + tbSearchByUsername.Text + "'";
        }

        if (ddList_Type.Text != "")
        {
            searchQuery += "AND Type ='" + ddList_Type.Text + ":'";
        }

        if (ddList_Forum.Text != "All forums")
        {
            searchQuery += "AND forumName ='" + ddList_Forum.Text + "'";
        }


        var results = ds.Tables[0].Select(searchQuery);
        resultDS.Tables.Add();

        foreach (DataRow dr in results)
        {
            resultDS.Tables[0].ImportRow(dr);
        }

        resultDS.AcceptChanges();
        gridView_IndexData.DataSource = resultDS.Tables[0];
        ViewState["searchListActive"] = true;
        ViewState["resultDS"] = resultDS;
        gridView_IndexData.DataBind();

    }

    protected void gridView_IndexData_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSortDirection(e.SortDirection.ToString());
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + _sortDirection;
        gridView_IndexData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gridView_IndexData.DataBind();
    }

    void SetSortDirection(string sortDirection)
    {
        if (sortDirection == "Descending")
        {
            _sortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            _sortDirection = "ASC";
        }
    }

    protected void gridView_IndexData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridView_IndexData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        if ((bool)ViewState["searchListActive"] == true)
        {
            gridView_IndexData.DataSource = (DataSet)ViewState["resultDS"];
        }
        gridView_IndexData.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of proper xml handling such as using an xmlreader. Here is an article with pointers on that (http://forums.asp.net/t/1939295.aspx?Most+efficient+way+to+iterate+through+XML). And, by all means maximize your use of caching when possible. Here are a few pointers on that ([Data Caching in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462298/data-caching-in-asp-net?rq=1)).

Comment: Thanks. 
I cached whole dataset on Client side and that made postbacks Load in seconds. I also did other changes. I created XML Schema and instead of using Select() of dataset, I'm using lambda expression to get topics. That saved at least one second for searching in my tests, while XML Schema did reduce load time quite a bunch. Instead for 30, page now loads in seconds. I gave both you and shadi upvote, however my reputation is low for that...

Answer (score 2):

1) if you will share same dataset instance it will give you errors when concurrent users searching in same time

2) to optimize search speed convert your structure to LINQ instead of dataset queries